# Printing the Contents of Nested lists With unknown Depths

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a directory output, and it is going to be a series of nested loops where the first item in the list is a sub-directory, which may or may not contain sub-directories themselves.
Example:

`directory=[["$Recycle.Bin","S-1-5-18"],["AutoDesk",["AutoCad","File1","File2","File3"],["Inventor","project1"],["WI","Copyright"]]]`

This would as a directory look like:

```
$Recycle.Bin
    ->S-1-5-18
AutoDesk
    -> AutoCad
        ->File1
        ->File2
        ->File3
    -> Inventor
        ->project1
    -> WI
        ->Copyright
```

and the output of the function would be:
print the directory name, and then all items in the directory so that I can add them to the GUI.  I just can't figure out how to determine if something is an object in a list of another set of nested lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out if something is a list, do this:

```
if isinstance(obj, list):
    do_list_stuff(obj)
```